# Cant get a function with jquery to work

Tags: jquery, function

The following code below works fine:

```
$("#searchTab").click(function(){
$(".tab").addClass("tabNo");
$(".tab").removeClass("tabYes");
$(this).addClass("tabYes");
$(".content").hide();
$("#searchContent").show();
});
```

but if I try to organize the code into a function like below it does not work. Only "$(".content").hide();" from the function seem to work. Why is that?

```
function tabSelect(){
$(".tab").addClass("tabNo");
$(".tab").removeClass("tabYes");
$(this).addClass("tabYes");
$(".content").hide();
}

$("#searchTab").click(function(){
    tabSelect();
    $("#searchContent").show();
});
```

Comment: Using `this` as a reference to the element no longer works. You need to pass it as an argument ... (or use `call` as patrick dw shows, nice!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `this` reference has changed. You'll need to pass it as an argument to `tabSelect`, or wrap it and use the wrapper. (`$(this)`)

```
function tabSelect($itemToTab){
$(".tab").addClass("tabNo");
$(".tab").removeClass("tabYes");
$itemToTab.addClass("tabYes");
$(".content").hide();
}

$("#searchTab").click(function(){
    tabSelect($(this));
    $("#searchContent").show();
});
```

Comment: correct. $(this) inside a function refers to the function object, in the click function was referring the the clicked element.

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
tabSelect();
```

to this:

```
tabSelect.call( this );
```

This manually sets the value of `this` in the calling context of `tabSelect()`.

```
function tabSelect(){
    $(".tab").addClass("tabNo").removeClass("tabYes");  // chain these!
    $(this).addClass("tabYes");  // now "this" is the element you're expecting
    $(".content").hide();
}

$("#searchTab").click(function(){
    tabSelect.call( this ); // set "this" in the calling context of "tabSelect"
                            //   to the current value of "this" (the element)
    $("#searchContent").show();
});
```